# How to compare two contours translated from one another's position?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

Image:http://answers.opencv.org/upfiles/1392627645523812.jpg
Hi all,
      I want to compare two contours & find the hausdorff distance between them to find the similarity between the two contours. When I take the template contour on the Right side as a Reference Template Contour to find the similar contour from the Left hand side I’m getting error because the Scene contour points are translated from the Template contour points. Actually I’m taking the contours points directly from the two images.  As you can see I cannot crop only the contour region since it affects the neighboring contours.

Should I make an Empty image with Scene image size and make my Template contour slide over the Scene Image to find the match? or else is there any other better approach?
Regards,
Balaji.R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

1. Detect the contours in your original image.
2. Get the contours sequence/points for each contour. For example, lets say the first start is  stored as point-1, point-2, point-3 etc in the contour-1 (just a rough example).
3. Then find the minimum and maximum x and y coordinate for each contour.
4. For each contour `width = max_x - min_x`  and  `height = max_y - min_y`
5. Then create individual image for each contour by

   regionOfInterest =  Rect(min_x, min_y, width, height)
   templateImage = originalImage(regionOfInterest);
6. Now, perform the matchTemplate(); between each individual template image (created from each contour) and the original image and then you can find the location of Maximum coorlation.
7. If you think that the scale of the template image can also vary then you can `pryUp()` or `pryDown()` on template image.